# GET variables disappear, after changing action on form by jQuery.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I trying to change action url on form, by jQuery. I have this code.

```
<form id='form_a' action='browse.php' method='get'>
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" id='but_a'>
</form>
<script>
    var def = [];
    $('.attr_color').change(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            def.push($(this).val());
        } else {
            def.splice($.inArray($(this).val(), def), 1);
        }
        color = "&attr_color=" + def.join(",");
        if (def.length === 0) {
            color = "";
        }
        $('#form_a').get(0).setAttribute('action', "browse.php?" + color);
    });
</script>
```

When I inspect code by Chrome inspect, form action, is changing, but after the form is send, everything after "`browse.php`?" disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `method="get"`, all the URL parameters come from the form fields, you can't put URL parameters in the action.

If you want to send additional parameters, you should add hidden input fields to the form, not modify the URL.

Answer (score 0):

That's the `GET` behavior, see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp for more information.

What you want is to redirect your page and append the color variable in your query string.
You can do this in javascript:

```
window.location.replace("/browse.php?" + color);
```